# Printing alphabets from a to z every time

Tags: php

I am using the below php code to list Alphabetical(A-Z) characters in the rows. It works fine from a to z. My problem is that after "z", it starts with aa, ab,ac, etc.. I'd like it to start with a to z again every time it comes to z. 
How can achieve this? thanks.

```
 <?php 

    foreach (range('a', 'z') as $char)
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
      { 
      echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<td>" .$char.  "</td>"; 
      $char++;
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp1'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp2'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp3'] . "</td>";  
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp4'] . "</td>";   
      echo "</tr>"; 
      }
    ?>
```

I tried below solution but it ended up with the same result.

```
<?php 

        $char= 'a';
        for($i=0;$i<26;$i++)
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
          { 
          echo "<tr>"; 
          echo "<td>" .$char.  "</td>"; 
          $char++;
          echo "<td>" . $row['Rp1'] . "</td>"; 
          echo "<td>" . $row['Rp2'] . "</td>"; 
          echo "<td>" . $row['Rp3'] . "</td>";  
          echo "<td>" . $row['Rp4'] . "</td>";   
          echo "</tr>"; 
          }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize PHP's built-in array functions for handling internal array pointers:

```
$range = range('a', 'z');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . current($range) .  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp1'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp3'] . "</td>";  
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp4'] . "</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";

    if (next($range) !== false) {
        reset($range);
    }
}
```

Checkout these references to learn more:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Answer (score 2):

You can reference your array of letters by a calculated value, `$i % 26`, where `$i` is the zero based iteration count of your while loop.

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $letters[$i++ % 26] .  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp1'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp3'] . "</td>";  
    echo "<td>" . $row['Rp4'] . "</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, get the characters from a to z in an array.
- Initialize a counter (index) to access a specific character from the array.
- Increment the counter inside loop.
- If the counter value goes above 25 (index starts from 0 - so this represents 26th array item), reset its value back to zero.

Try the following:

```
<?php 

    // get array for characters from a to z
    $characters = range('a', 'z');

    $counter = 0; // initialize the counter (index)

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
    { 
      echo "<tr>"; 

      // access the character using counter index
      echo "<td>" . $characters[$counter] .  "</td>"; 

      // Increment the counter
      $counter++;
      // Check and reset if the counter has gone above 25 (26th array item)
      $counter = ($counter > 25 ? 0 : $counter);

      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp1'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp2'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp3'] . "</td>";  
      echo "<td>" . $row['Rp4'] . "</td>";   
      echo "</tr>"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , Madhur. I tried it, but it didn't work in my case. I use another counter too at the beginning of my code as well.

Comment: @Max is it also named `$counter` ? If yes, you can simply rename the counter I have mentioned in my code to something else.